# R density scatter from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have this pseudobulk single cell dataset.

```
se1 <- MakePseudoBulk(scData, group.var = "sample_type", assay = "RNA", sample_id = NA, verbose = F)
```

I'm now correlation two different categories on a scatterplot:

```
# Use the log2 normalized counts; this way it is dominated by highly expressed genes
counts <- assays(se1)$log2_tmm_cpm

# get column names for counts matrix
colnames(counts)

# choose columns for plotting
data.plot <- counts[, c(1, 2, 3)]

ggplot(data.frame(data.plot), aes(x = data.plot[, 1], y = data.plot[, 2], label = rownames(counts))) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "FLEX_single-cell vs FLEX_tissue", x = "FLEX_single-cell", y = "FLEX_tissue") +
  stat_cor() +
  geom_text(nudge_x = 0.3, nudge_y = 0.3)
```

Now I'm trying to use density scatter to show where there is commonality across genes by doing this:

density_scatter_plot

```
# Create a function to generate density scatter plot
density_scatter_plot <- function(data, x_col, y_col, title, x_label, y_label) {
  ggplot(data, aes(x = .data[[x_col]], y = .data[[y_col]])) +
    geom_pointdensity() + scale_color_viridis() + # Use geom_pointdensity
    labs(title = title, x = x_label, y = y_label) +
    stat_cor()
}



# Create and save density scatter plots for each comparison
plot1 <- density_scatter_plot(data.plot, "FLEX_single.cell", "FLEX_tissue", "FLEX_single.cell vs FLEX_tissue", "FLEX_single.cell", "FLEX_tissue")
```

But I get this results, that look strange, how to fix the function?

```
> head(data.plot)
  FLEX_single.cell FLEX_tissue Fresh_single.cell
1         2.952484    3.437738          3.427664
2         6.406967    6.361295          5.431862
3         2.591572    3.468295          2.005410
4         3.361154    3.180253          2.434913
5         1.861162    2.256375          1.975780
6         6.226052    6.038626          7.552368
```

[image],

Comment: Hi mmpp. Which package is MakePseudoBulk from? What is `scData`? Are you able to provide a data set that we can use to replicate your problem? Can you specify what you think is strange about your output? To me it looks like there is a large density spike at the origin, but if that's what your data shows, how would you like to  change the appearance of your plot? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Allan, MakePseudoBulk is an internal package. I'm expecting the center to have more diversity.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a log color scale?

Comment: How would that script look like?

Comment: Really hard to say without a reproducible example, mmpp.

Comment: Perhsps you could try increasing the bandwidth by adding `adjust = 5` or `adjust = 10` to `geom_pointdensity`

Comment: Hi Allan, I added an example of the data.

Comment: thanks.  Your plot suggests that the problem is almost certainly that you have a large number of points at `[0, 0]`. You will get the variation to show differing densities if you remove these points as I show below. Did any of the solutions work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is just the appearance you get when you have a huge number of points clustered at a single location (in this case, the origin). If you have, say, 20,000 points all at exactly the origin, then there will be a circular region with a neighbor count of 20,000 within a fixed distance from the origin. This will then fall off to a value of 1,000 or so outside a 1 bandwidth radius of the origin. Even fairly large changes in the density outside the origin circle are difficult to see because it is still tiny compared to the size of the density at the origin.

We can replicate it by making a bivariate normal cloud with loads of extra points added at exactly c(0, 0):

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- as.data.frame(rbind(MASS::mvrnorm(n = 20000, mu = c(0, 0), 
                      Sigma = matrix(c(3, 3, 4, 4), ncol = 2)),
                    as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 20000))))


df <- setNames(df, c("x", "y"))
```

Now we have:

```r
library(ggpointdensity)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_pointdensity() +
  scale_color_viridis_c() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 8), x = c(0, 8), expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

There are various ways to improve the apparent variability of the density. You could just remove all those points that are causing the problem at the origin:

```r
ggplot(df[df[[1]] > 0.01 & df[[2]] > 0.01,], aes(x, y)) +
  geom_pointdensity() +
  scale_color_viridis_c() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 8), x = c(0, 8), expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

Or change the limits of `scale_color_viridis`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_pointdensity() +
  scale_color_viridis_c(limits = c(0, 3000), na.value = "#f5e51f") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 8), x = c(0, 8), expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

Or use a logarithmic color scale:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_pointdensity(aes(color = after_stat(log(n_neighbors)))) +
  scale_color_viridis_c() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 8), x = c(0, 8), expand = FALSE)
```

[image]